# AlarmManager repeating alarm stopped to work

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an app with AlarmManager to remind once a week about something. It was working fine but now probably after migrating to the new target api it stopped. I have added the required now flag IMMUTABLE so that the app is not throwing exception but the alarm is still not showing up :|
I have this code:

```
long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();//here I am setting the time by the UI one minute ahead
long alarmInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, alarmIntent);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = getPendingIntent(context, i);
...
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, int day)
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getNotificationPublisherClass());
        final int flag =  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT;
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, day, intent, flag);
}
```

and in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".Code.BroadcastReceivers.NotificationPublisher" android:enabled="true"/>
```

I have read that now all those alarms can be not precise and run after the set time but I am using emulator with screen on so if the phone is not slipping the I believe it should fire maybe not exactly at the set time but close enough. I have waited few minutes and nothing has been fired.

Comment: You could work around that by sending a notification from your app instead. That way you'd be running in a thread that will read the time much more accurately. There are some answers on how to do that here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation does not specify how inexact the repeating alarm is. Last time I tested in on emulator it was about 15 minutes late on Android 13. If it's still not working, for test purposes try schedule exact alarm (permission needed) which should fire within 5 minutes.

Comment: @DerekK but is there a repeating exact timer?

Comment: @Winston this would require my app to be running all the time which is not possible and absolutely harmful to battery I suppose.

Comment: No, I mean try `setExact` (not repeating), just for test to localize possible bug in your code.